# Underactuated instalationl issue ( Follow Text book A3.2 Download the textbook supplement)

Tags: drake

It is embarrassed that I can't solve this installation issue. The exactly same installation can be done in MacBook, but suffer some issue for another mac pro. I need this faster computer for optimization.

The error message are:
**

```
Mac-Pro ~ % underactuated/scripts/setup/mac/install_prereqs
Already up-to-date.
Error: Calling brew tap-pin user/tap is disabled! Use fully-scoped user/tap/formula naming instead.
Installing bazel has failed!
Using buildifier
Using ffmpeg
Using tidy-html5
Homebrew Bundle failed! 1 Brewfile dependency failed to install.


I try to solve by re-install Bazel by following command, but it still fail.
$ brew uninstall bazel
$ brew tap bazelbuild/tap
$ brew install bazelbuild/tap/bazel
```

**

```
The information are enclosed as following:
(1)
mcOS Catalina
10.15.5 Beta（19F72f）
MacPro6,1
(2)
Python version 2.7.16
Python3 version 3.7.7

(3) bazel version
Build label: 3.0.0
Build target: bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Mon Apr 6 12:55:48 2020 (1586177748)
Build timestamp: 1586177748
Build timestamp as int: 1586177748

(4) cmake --version
cmake version 3.17.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

(5) git rev-parse --short HEAD
c976d29
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Please untap `bazelbuild/tap` and remove `bazel`.
2. Try `brew install bazel`. If you get any error messages from it, please share them here.
3. Re-run `underactuated/scripts/setup/mac/install_prereqs` and check how it works. If it exits with error messages, please let us know.

Comment: The error message `Calling brew tap-pin user/tap is disabled!` indicates that you might use a very old commit of underactuated, while the mentioned output of `git rev-parse --short HEAD
c`, `c976d29` implies that you're on the latest `master` (as of 2020/05/05). Can you double-check you're on `c976d29`? For example, `scripts/setup/mac/Brewfile` should be the same as https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/scripts/setup/mac/Brewfile.

Comment: I want to check the result for your instructions, but it is too late. Just before I see your answer, I reinstalled OS to make every thing clean. Now it works! Thank you anyway!